# Converting nested JSON to Data Frame in R

Tags: r, json

I have a pretty long JSON list that I'm looking to convert into a a data frame. I'm hoping someone can help me figure it out.

```
    {"body":{"overall_standings":{"years":[{"standings":null,"id":"2006"},{"standings":null,"id":"2007"},{"standings":null,"id":"2008"},{"standings":null,"id":"2009"},{"standings":null,"id":"2010"},{"standings":null,"id":"2011"},{"standings":{"teams":[{"Pitching":{"roto_points":"47.0","categories":[{"abbr":"S","roto_points":"91","value":"New York Yankees","diff":"9","rank":5},{"roto_points":"90","value":"New York Yankees","abbr":"W","diff":"7","rank":7},{"roto_points":"1383","value":"New York Yankees","abbr":"K","diff":"10","rank":4},{"abbr":"WHIP","roto_points":"1.2451","value":"New York Yankees","diff":"10","rank":4},{"abbr":"ERA","roto_points":"3.685","value":"New York Yankees","diff":"11","rank":3}]},"Total":{"behind":"0.0","roto_points":"98.0","diff":"-4.0","rank":1},"order":1,"name":"New York Yankees","Batting":{"roto_points":"51.0","categories":[{"abbr":"OBP","roto_points":"0.3371","value":"New York Yankees","diff":"7","rank":7},{"roto_points":"905","value":"New York Yankees","abbr":"RBI","diff":"10","rank":4},{"roto_points":"955","value":"New York Yankees","abbr":"R","diff":"12","rank":2},{"abbr":"SB","roto_points":"183","value":"New York Yankees","diff":"13","rank":1},{"abbr":"HR","roto_points":"247","value":"New York Yankees","diff":"9","rank":5}]},"id":"2"},{"Pitching":{"roto_points":"44.5","categories":[{"abbr":"S","roto_points":"105","value":"Los Angeles Dodgers","diff":"12","rank":2},{"roto_points":"96","value":"Los Angeles Dodgers","abbr":"W","diff":"10.5","rank":3},{"roto_points":"1410","value":"Los Angeles Dodgers","abbr":"K","diff":"11","rank":3},{"abbr":"WHIP","roto_points":"1.2798","value":"Los Angeles Dodgers","diff":"3","rank":11},{"abbr":"ERA","roto_points":"3.810","value":"Los Angeles Dodgers","diff":"8","rank":6}]},"Total":{"behind":"4.0","roto_points":"94.0","diff":"0.0","rank":2},"order":2,"name":"Los Angeles Dodgers","Batting":{"roto_points":"49.5","categories":[{"abbr":"OBP","roto_points":"0.3446","value":"Los Angeles Dodgers","diff":"11","rank":3},{"roto_points":"907","value":"Los Angeles Dodgers","abbr":"RBI","diff":"11","rank":3},{"roto_points":"909","value":"Los Angeles Dodgers","abbr":"R","diff":"9","rank":5},{"abbr":"SB","roto_points":"152","value":"Los Angeles Dodgers","diff":"11","rank":3},{"abbr":"HR","roto_points":"234","value":"Los Angeles Dodgers","diff":"7.5","rank":6}]},"id":"1"}]},"id":"2012"}]}}}
```

After the comma the list continues through until id 2017.

```
    {"standings":{"teams":[{"Pitching":{"roto_points":"40.5","categories":[{"abbr":"S","roto_points":"100","value":"Los Angeles
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Jazzmatazz, it helps to have a json string that can be parsed, this is incomplete. If you remove the last comma from the first string and add `]}}}` it makes it complete-enough for the json libraries to parse without complaining.

Comment: It would really help to know what you've tried so far and what you expect in the output. In this case, I suggest you manually go through (perhaps with Excel or Calc) and generate the derived column names and contents for at least a few rows. (From the looks of it, the top three levels can be dropped, and two of the lists appear to be identically-structured frames that can be reduced.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with parsing JSON.  I didn't include the end of the data frame since it's really long.  I want the columns to be id (which is the year), the other id (team id number), roto points, value, diff, rank, behind, etc.

Comment: You did not include a `data.frame`, that's a string, but the point is that it is not a complete JSON string. That's okay, I hope it's sufficient if terminated (as above). (Really long data is not typically necessary on SO, so you're fine.) Look at [`jsonlite`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html) and [`rjson`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/index.html).

Comment: I figured it would take jsonlite, I just am not sure how to use them to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kinda ugly. I really want somebody to come up with a better answer, especially since it keeps the nested frames, making subsetting a bit painful.

```
js <- jsonlite::fromJSON('{"body":{"overall_standings":{"years":[{"standings":null,"id":"2006"},{"standings":null,"id":"2007"},{"standings":null,"id":"2008"},{"standings":null,"id":"2009"},{"standings":null,"id":"2010"},{"standings":null,"id":"2011"},{"standings":{"teams":[{"Pitching":{"roto_points":"47.0","categories":[{"abbr":"S","roto_points":"91","value":"New York Yankees","diff":"9","rank":5},{"roto_points":"90","value":"New York Yankees","abbr":"W","diff":"7","rank":7},{"roto_points":"1383","value":"New York Yankees","abbr":"K","diff":"10","rank":4},{"abbr":"WHIP","roto_points":"1.2451","value":"New York Yankees","diff":"10","rank":4},{"abbr":"ERA","roto_points":"3.685","value":"New York Yankees","diff":"11","rank":3}]},"Total":{"behind":"0.0","roto_points":"98.0","diff":"-4.0","rank":1},"order":1,"name":"New York Yankees","Batting":{"roto_points":"51.0","categories":[{"abbr":"OBP","roto_points":"0.3371","value":"New York Yankees","diff":"7","rank":7},{"roto_points":"905","value":"New York Yankees","abbr":"RBI","diff":"10","rank":4},{"roto_points":"955","value":"New York Yankees","abbr":"R","diff":"12","rank":2},{"abbr":"SB","roto_points":"183","value":"New York Yankees","diff":"13","rank":1},{"abbr":"HR","roto_points":"247","value":"New York Yankees","diff":"9","rank":5}]},"id":"2"},{"Pitching":{"roto_points":"44.5","categories":[{"abbr":"S","roto_points":"105","value":"Los Angeles Dodgers","diff":"12","rank":2},{"roto_points":"96","value":"Los Angeles Dodgers","abbr":"W","diff":"10.5","rank":3},{"roto_points":"1410","value":"Los Angeles Dodgers","abbr":"K","diff":"11","rank":3},{"abbr":"WHIP","roto_points":"1.2798","value":"Los Angeles Dodgers","diff":"3","rank":11},{"abbr":"ERA","roto_points":"3.810","value":"Los Angeles Dodgers","diff":"8","rank":6}]},"Total":{"behind":"4.0","roto_points":"94.0","diff":"0.0","rank":2},"order":2,"name":"Los Angeles Dodgers","Batting":{"roto_points":"49.5","categories":[{"abbr":"OBP","roto_points":"0.3446","value":"Los Angeles Dodgers","diff":"11","rank":3},{"roto_points":"907","value":"Los Angeles Dodgers","abbr":"RBI","diff":"11","rank":3},{"roto_points":"909","value":"Los Angeles Dodgers","abbr":"R","diff":"9","rank":5},{"abbr":"SB","roto_points":"152","value":"Los Angeles Dodgers","diff":"11","rank":3},{"abbr":"HR","roto_points":"234","value":"Los Angeles Dodgers","diff":"7.5","rank":6}]},"id":"1"}]},"id":"2012"}]}}}')
```

It starts as a list within a list within a list, so let's get rid of the unneeded layers. (I'm showing intermediate code that is just demonstrative, no output, since it's rather verbose ... thinking I'm walking you through.)

```
str(js[[1]])
str(js[[1]][[1]])
str(js[[1]][[1]][[1]])
dat <- js[[1]][[1]][[1]]
```

On that last `str`, you may notice that `dat$standings$teams` has quite a few `NULL`s, let's filter them out:

```
dat <- Filter(length, dat$standings$teams)[[1]]
```

Ok, a quick helper-function and the output:

```
library(dplyr)
addnames <- function(x, nm, sep = "_") setNames(x, paste0(nm, sep, colnames(x)))
dat2 <- tbl_df(bind_cols(
  dat[c("id","name","order")],
  addnames(dat$Total, "Total"),
  addnames(dat$Pitching["roto_points"], "Pitching"),
  addnames(dat$Batting["roto_points"], "Batting")
)) %>%
  mutate(
    Pitching_categories = dat$Pitching$categories,
    Batting_categories = dat$Batting$categories
  ) 
dat2
# # A tibble: 2 x 11
#   id    name                order Total_behind Total_roto_points Total_diff Total_rank Pitching_roto_points Batting_roto_points Pitching_categories  Batting_categories  
#   <chr> <chr>               <int> <chr>        <chr>             <chr>           <int> <chr>                <chr>               <list>               <list>              
# 1 2     New York Yankees        1 0.0          98.0              -4.0                1 47.0                 51.0                <data.frame [5 x 5]> <data.frame [5 x 5]>
# 2 1     Los Angeles Dodgers     2 4.0          94.0              0.0                 2 44.5                 49.5                <data.frame [5 x 5]> <data.frame [5 x 5]>
```

This has two nested frames, so you'll to be a little creative when working with them. I suggest that this is not the best way to look at it, but it's a start. It is certainly possible (with some more elbow grease) to expand these two rows (one per team) to be ten rows (five per team, reflecting the five rows nested in each of `Pitching` and `Batting`), but that may not be what you need.

```
unnest(dat2)
# # A tibble: 10 x 19
#    id    name       order Total_behind Total_roto_points Total_diff Total_rank Pitching_roto_poi~ Batting_roto_po~ abbr  roto_points value     diff   rank abbr1 roto_points1 value1    diff1 rank1
#    <chr> <chr>      <int> <chr>        <chr>             <chr>           <int> <chr>              <chr>            <chr> <chr>       <chr>     <chr> <int> <chr> <chr>        <chr>     <chr> <int>
#  1 2     New York ~     1 0.0          98.0              -4.0                1 47.0               51.0             S     91          New York~ 9         5 OBP   0.3371       New York~ 7         7
#  2 2     New York ~     1 0.0          98.0              -4.0                1 47.0               51.0             W     90          New York~ 7         7 RBI   905          New York~ 10        4
#  3 2     New York ~     1 0.0          98.0              -4.0                1 47.0               51.0             K     1383        New York~ 10        4 R     955          New York~ 12        2
#  4 2     New York ~     1 0.0          98.0              -4.0                1 47.0               51.0             WHIP  1.2451      New York~ 10        4 SB    183          New York~ 13        1
#  5 2     New York ~     1 0.0          98.0              -4.0                1 47.0               51.0             ERA   3.685       New York~ 11        3 HR    247          New York~ 9         5
#  6 1     Los Angel~     2 4.0          94.0              0.0                 2 44.5               49.5             S     105         Los Ange~ 12        2 OBP   0.3446       Los Ange~ 11        3
#  7 1     Los Angel~     2 4.0          94.0              0.0                 2 44.5               49.5             W     96          Los Ange~ 10.5      3 RBI   907          Los Ange~ 11        3
#  8 1     Los Angel~     2 4.0          94.0              0.0                 2 44.5               49.5             K     1410        Los Ange~ 11        3 R     909          Los Ange~ 9         5
#  9 1     Los Angel~     2 4.0          94.0              0.0                 2 44.5               49.5             WHIP  1.2798      Los Ange~ 3        11 SB    152          Los Ange~ 11        3
# 10 1     Los Angel~     2 4.0          94.0              0.0                 2 44.5               49.5             ERA   3.810       Los Ange~ 8         6 HR    234          Los Ange~ 7.5       6
```

Like I said, this does not seem pretty or even elegant, but perhaps it's a good start for you, or maybe somebody else can spring-board off this for a better solution.

Comment: Thanks!  It gets me exactly what I needed into a data frame.  I'm certainly open to a more elegant solution, but just happy to get a solution!

Comment: How do I include the year as a column as well?  There are additional years after 2012.